# Outlook web add-ins randomly disappearing from ribbon

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have encountered a very curious issue where Outlook web add-ins randomly disappear from the ribbon. The issue seems to be only reproducible in Office365 MSO 16.0.10827.20118 (32 bit).

Comment: Please add more detail about the circumstances of the random disappearing. Do all Add-ins disappear or just a few, and do other parts of the ribbon disappear as well? Does it happen when both writing a message and reading an existing message? Are there any required conditions, such as having an Add-in already open or having not opened an Add-in yet? And finally, how consistent is this repro, and are all your users seeing it or just you? Please feel free to update the original question and reply here when done.

Comment: We tested with a third party add-in along with our own and noticed that all plugins disappear when the issue occurs. The issue occurs in read and compose mode. It is only occurring for one of our customers (having multiple users).

Comment: Could the user have multiple email account setup with Outlook? (addins are specific to an account and would not show if the user switches account).  Or could the user be reading group messages or IRM protected messages where addins are not supported?

Comment: I have a user who's experiencing this. Our addin won't show on the ribbon, but when the user checks in the Store, it does say that our addin is installed. When the user uninstalls the addin and installs again, it shows up. Version 16.19 (181109) on Mac.